# Pre-define colors for Terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was trying to remember how I could pre-define colors inside of `.bashrc` file so they could be called on when I do `${RED}` for example.

I can't remember if this was the right way of doing it, but it was something like this if I can remember;

```
NC="\033[0;0;0m"      # no color or formatting
RED="\033[1;49;91m"   # color red
BLU="\033[1;49;94m"   # color blue
GRN="\033[1;49;32m"   # color green
```

another I recall, was using `function` so it could be use at any time anywhere. I did have a file showing me how to do this but I lost this file which showed how to do it, and I can't remember how it goes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a function in your `~/.bashrc` as follows

```
showred(){
    export RED='\033[1;49;91m'
    export NC='\033[0;0;0m'
    echo -e $RED"$@"$NC
}
```

Source `~/.bashrc` as `. ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal and try.

[image]

Also you can write in colours while writing something on terminal using `echo` or `printf` as following,

[image]

Comment: This seems like a friendlier and cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare -r RED='\033[0;31m'
declare -r GREEN='\033[0;32m'
declare -r NC='\033[0m'
```

Answer (score 3):

You may have seen the [`$'...'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) syntax, which causes the shell to interpret backslash sequences:

```
NC=$'\e[0m'       # no color or formatting
RED=$'\e[1;31m'   # color red
GRN=$'\e[1;32m'   # color green
BLU=$'\e[1;34m'   # color blue
```

Another way to do this, using [tput](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tput):

```
NC=$(tput sgr0)                  # no color or formatting
RED=$(tput bold; tput setaf 1)   # color red
GRN=$(tput bold; tput setaf 2)   # color green
BLU=$(tput bold; tput setaf 4)   # color blue
```

You can combine these with the wrapper functions in souravc's answer; you won't need `-e`.